# JTree and TreeModel with hierarchy of varying class?

Tags: java, swing, model, jtree, treemodel

I have a hierarchy of objects that I would like to show using a JTree and TreeModel. Each level of the hierarchy is a different class.

All the examples of JTree and TreeModel I've seen have a common class throughout the entire hierarchy of the tree (i.e. File for a file system browser). How do you go about implementing TreeModel when your hierarchy changes class from level-to-level? Do you put TreeModel inside TreeModel?

Comment: do you mean you have a collections of object and you want the collections to display in a TreeModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement TreeModel and then supply your own implementation of methods. JTree works with Objects, so you should be fine with multiple types.